# Upload file in chunks with progress bar

Tags: ruby, http, post, file-upload, upload

I want to upload a file in chunks while updating a progress bar after each chunk, in ruby, preferably without the implementation of any gems or plugins.

I have this POST:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://some/url")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req['some'] = 'header'
req.body_stream = File.new('some.file')
req.content_length = File.size('some.file')
res = https.request req
```

It uploads the file in one single piece in this line:

```
res = https.request req
```

I want to update a progress bar on the side.

The reverse, downloading with a progress bar in pure ruby is easy, and you can find references like this:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/large_file')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  http.request request do |response|
    open 'large_file', 'w' do |io|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write chunk
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do something similar as above, but for uploads in Ruby?